# Finding the maximal interval of existence of solution of an IVP

Tags: initial-value-problems

I have this question asked in an exam:

> The solution to $$
> \left\{
> \begin{aligned}
> \frac{dy}{dx} &= y^2+x^2  \quad , x \gt 0 \\
> y(0) &= 2 
> \end{aligned}
> \right.
> $$
>   exists in the interval $[0, L_0)$ and the maximal interval of existence of $$
> \left\{
> \begin{aligned}
> \frac{dz}{dx} &= z^2 \quad , x\gt 0 \\
> z(0) &= 1
> \end{aligned}
> \right.$$
>   is $[0,L_1) $.

I have to find the values of $L_0$ and $L_1$.

In the second case the conditions of **Existence and Uniqueness theorem** are satisfied in every rectangle $$|x| \le a, \quad  |z-1| \le b$$ about the point $(0,1)$.Now if $M $
is maximum of $z^2$  and $h= min(a,b/M) $ then the IVP possess a solution on $|x| \le h$.

After calculating I get $h=1/4$ , so will I conclude that $L_1 = 1/4$ ?

Also in the 1st case I am unable to find $L_0$.

Any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation is easy to solve in closed form, and you can see from that closed form where the solution goes to $\infty$, giving you $L_1$.

The first equation has a complicated closed-form solution in terms of Bessel functions, which nobody would expect you to find on an exam.  Fortunately it doesn't ask for the **maximal** interval of existence in this case, just **an** interval of existence.  So you can
choose some convenient $R > 2$ and find some $L_0$ for which you can prove that the solution will stay in the interval $[2,  R]$ for $0 \le x < L_0$.  Thus if you take $R = 3$, 
$y' = y^2 + x^2 < 10$ if $2 \le y \le 3$ and $0 < x < 1$, and so the solution is
guaranteed to exist at least on $[0, 1/10)$.

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with closed form solution,so it's hard to make out your answer, will you please give any other way solving. @RobertIsrael

Comment: "Closed form" just means an explicit formula for the solution: $y = \ldots$.

Comment: Oh! I got the closed form solution ! But how the solution is guaranteed on $[0,1/10)$ ? , Will you explain please.

Comment: In order for the solution to go to $\infty$, it must first get to $y=3$.  While in the rectangle $0 \le x \le 1$, $2 \le y \le 3$ the slope $y' \le 10$, so $y(1/10) \le 2 + 10/10 = 3$.